# GSheet: Query rows within date range in different columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a [spread sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kMYIbgQ29GSNBp8yq4FFl54Rp2IdOmsWt4fHL91SY3o/edit?usp=sharing) with a list of names for which there are a specified date ranges. What I'm trying to achieve is to get the name of the person whose date range falls within the current week.

[image: data source]

So far I've come up with this query but it does not return the correct name. What it actually does is just return the first 2 names without any regard to the where clause conditions.

```
=QUERY(A2:C;"SELECT A WHERE B >= "&TODAY()&" AND C <= "&TODAY()+6&" LIMIT 0";2)
```

[image: result with just first 2 rows]

I can't figure out what could be the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(A2:C; 
 "select A 
  where B >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY();   "e-m-d")&"' 
    and C <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY()+6; "e-m-d")&"'"; 0)
```